# NHibernate second level caching not working with HashTableCacheProvider

Tags: nhibernate, caching

I'm basically just trying to reproduce the Ayende's first and second level caching http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/28/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate .

I've wired up the configuration as:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory name="NHibernate.Test">
  <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver</property>
  <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>
  <property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
  <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
  <property name="cache.provider_class">NHibernate.Cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>
  <property name="cache.default_expiration">1801</property>
</session-factory>
```

and I've mapped the entity as:

```
<class name="HeaderDTO" mutable="false" check="none">
<cache usage="read-write"/>
  <id name="Id" type="System.Int32" >
    <column name="id" sql-type="NUMBER" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
    <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>
  <property name="Description" column="description" type="System.String" />
</class>
```

and my named query looks like this:

```
<sql-query name="GetHeaderDTO">
  <query-param name="id" type="int"/>
  <return class="HeaderDTO" />
  { call MyPackage.get_header(:id) }
</sql-query>
```

and now I'm trying to do some tests (ignore the fact the test is not a very good one to test caching).

```
[TestMethod]
public void Cacching_Entity_FirstCallIsCached()
{
DateTime StartTime;
DateTime EndTime;
TimeSpan FirstTry;
TimeSpan SecondTry;
int Id = 2888469;
string key = string.Concat("Id", Id);

using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
{
    //Act
    var query = session.GetNamedQuery("GetHeaderDTO");
    query.SetInt32("in_nom_id", Id);
    query.SetCacheable(true);
    query.SetCacheMode(CacheMode.Normal);
    query.SetCacheRegion(key);
    StartTime = DateTime.Now;
    HeaderDTO MyHeader = query.UniqueResult<HeaderDTO>();
    EndTime = DateTime.Now;
    FirstTry = EndTime - StartTime;
}

using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
{
    //Act
    var query = session.GetNamedQuery("GetHeaderDTO");
    query.SetInt32("in_nom_id", Id);
    query.SetCacheable(true);
    StartTime = DateTime.Now;
    HeaderDTO MyHeader = query.UniqueResult<HeaderDTO>();
    EndTime = DateTime.Now;
    SecondTry = EndTime - StartTime;
}

Assert.IsTrue(FirstTry>SecondTry);
}
```

But when I run the test and look at the NHibernate logs:

NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl: DEBUG [session-id=e9de687f-1ef5-4824-9964-9b94f636a15d] opened session at timestamp: 5517356014678016, for session factory: [NHibernate.Test/ca36467732ff486380672aeb062ef749]
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl: DEBUG setting cache mode to: Normal
NHibernate.Loader.Custom.Sql.SQLCustomQuery: DEBUG starting processing of sql query [{ call MyPackage.get_header(:id) }]
NHibernate.Loader.Custom.Sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor: DEBUG mapping alias [nh] to entity-suffix [0_]
NHibernate.Cache.StandardQueryCache: INFO  starting query cache at region: Id2888469
NHibernate.Cache.StandardQueryCache: DEBUG checking cached query results in region: 'Id2888469'; sql: { call MyPackage.get_header(?) }; parameters: []; named parameters: {'id'='2888469'}
NHibernate.Cache.StandardQueryCache: DEBUG query results were not found in cache: sql: { call MyPackage.get_header(?) }; parameters: []; named parameters: {'id'='2888469'}
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: DEBUG Opened new IDbCommand, open IDbCommands: 1
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: DEBUG Building an IDbCommand object for the SqlString: { call MyPackage.get_header(?) }
NHibernate.Type.Int32Type: DEBUG binding '2888469' to parameter: 0
NHibernate.Loader.Loader: INFO  { call MyPackage.get_header(:p0) }
NHibernate.SQL: DEBUG { call MyPackage.get_header(:p0) };:p0 = 2888469 [Type: Int32 (0)]
blah
blah
NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager: DEBUG aggressively releasing database connection
NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider: DEBUG Closing connection
NHibernate.Loader.Loader: DEBUG total objects hydrated: 1
NHibernate.Engine.TwoPhaseLoad: DEBUG resolving associations for [MyAssembly.HeaderDTO#2888469]
**NHibernate.Engine.TwoPhaseLoad: DEBUG adding entity to second-level cache: [MyAssembly.HeaderDTO#2888469]
NHibernate.Cache.ReadWriteCache: DEBUG Caching: MyAssembly.HeaderDTO#2888469
NHibernate.Cache.ReadWriteCache: DEBUG Cached: MyAssembly.HeaderDTO#2888469**
NHibernate.Engine.TwoPhaseLoad: DEBUG done materializing entity [MyAssembly.HeaderDTO#2888469]
NHibernate.Engine.StatefulPersistenceContext: DEBUG initializing non-lazy collections
NHibernate.Cache.StandardQueryCache: DEBUG caching query results in region: 'Id2888469'; sql: { call MyPackage.get_header(?) }; parameters: []; named parameters: {'id'='2888469'}
NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager: DEBUG after autocommit
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl: DEBUG transaction completion
NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager: DEBUG aggressively releasing database connection
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl: DEBUG setting cache mode to: Normal
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl: DEBUG [session-id=e9de687f-1ef5-4824-9964-9b94f636a15d] running ISession.Dispose()
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl: DEBUG [session-id=e9de687f-1ef5-4824-9964-9b94f636a15d] executing real Dispose(True)
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl: DEBUG closing session
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: DEBUG running BatcherImpl.Dispose(true)
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl: DEBUG [session-id=78820256-77e8-4596-8374-98f8b5cc946b] opened session at timestamp: 5517356016148480, for session factory: [NHibernate.Test/ca36467732ff486380672aeb062ef749]
NHibernate.Loader.Custom.Sql.SQLCustomQuery: DEBUG starting processing of sql query [{ call MyPackage.get_header(:id) }]
NHibernate.Loader.Custom.Sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor: DEBUG mapping alias [nh] to entity-suffix [0_]
NHibernate.Cache.StandardQueryCache: DEBUG checking cached query results in region: 'NHibernate.Cache.StandardQueryCache'; sql: { call MyPackage.get_header(?) }; parameters: []; named parameters: {'id'='2888469'}
**NHibernate.Cache.StandardQueryCache: DEBUG query results were not found in cache: sql: { call MyPackage.get_header(?) }; parameters: []; named parameters: {'id'='2888469'}**
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: DEBUG Opened new IDbCommand, open IDbCommands: 1
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: DEBUG Building an IDbCommand object for the SqlString: { call MyPackage.get_header(?) }
NHibernate.Type.Int32Type: DEBUG binding '2888469' to parameter: 0
NHibernate.Loader.Loader: INFO  { call MyPackage.get_header(:p0) }
NHibernate.SQL: DEBUG { call MyPackage.get_header(:p0) };:p0 = 2888469 [Type: Int32 (0)]
NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider: DEBUG Obtaining IDbConnection from Driver
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: DEBUG ExecuteReader took 2 ms
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: DEBUG Opened IDataReader, open IDataReaders: 
blah 
blah
NHibernate.Loader.Loader: DEBUG done processing result set (1 rows)
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: DEBUG Closed IDataReader, open IDataReaders :0
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: DEBUG DataReader was closed after 27 ms
blah
blah
NHibernate.Loader.Loader: DEBUG total objects hydrated: 1
NHibernate.Engine.TwoPhaseLoad: DEBUG resolving associations for [MyAssembly.HeaderDTO#2888469]
NHibernate.Engine.TwoPhaseLoad: DEBUG adding entity to second-level cache: [MyAssembly.HeaderDTO#2888469]
**NHibernate.Cache.ReadWriteCache: DEBUG Caching: MyAssembly.HeaderDTO#2888469
NHibernate.Cache.ReadWriteCache: DEBUG Item was already cached:** MyAssembly.HeaderDTO#2888469
NHibernate.Engine.TwoPhaseLoad: DEBUG done materializing entity [MyAssembly.HeaderDTO#2888469]
NHibernate.Engine.StatefulPersistenceContext: DEBUG initializing non-lazy collections
NHibernate.Cache.StandardQueryCache: DEBUG caching query results in region: 'NHibernate.Cache.StandardQueryCache'; sql: { call MyPackage.get_header(?) }; parameters: []; named parameters: {'id'='2888469'}
NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager: DEBUG after autocommit
blah 
blah

How can NHibernate say it was cached?  Can't find it and then NHibernate won't cache it because it is already cached?

Maybe it is something to do with HashTable provider?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Bill N

Comment: not sure at all, but maybe it has to do with the fact that you also have to mark your query as cachable

Comment: I thought I am when I set cacheable = true (query.SetCacheable(true);)

Comment: I think you might also need to specify it as cachable in your xml mapping

Comment: Haven't you already asked this question and GOT an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273302/nhibernate-second-level-caching-not-returning-object

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I think I am making the mapping cacheable in my xml when I applied the <cache usage="read-write"/>.  
@Rippo, no it is different.  I did have the caching setup like this with the SysCache provider and did indeed find that I was missing the <cache usage="read-write"/> in my xml.  However, I'm using Fluent NHibernate and can't use SysCache (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491876/nhibernate-3-3-and-syscache).  Now, i was just using the hashtable provider, and for whatever reason it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code in a transaction:

```
using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    //Act
    var query = session.GetNamedQuery("GetHeaderDTO");
    query.SetInt32("in_nom_id", Id);
    query.SetCacheable(true);
    query.SetCacheMode(CacheMode.Normal);
    query.SetCacheRegion(key);
    StartTime = DateTime.Now;
    HeaderDTO MyHeader = query.UniqueResult<HeaderDTO>();
    EndTime = DateTime.Now;
    FirstTry = EndTime - StartTime;

    tx.Commit();
}

using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    //Act
    var query = session.GetNamedQuery("GetHeaderDTO");
    query.SetInt32("in_nom_id", Id);
    query.SetCacheable(true);
    StartTime = DateTime.Now;
    HeaderDTO MyHeader = query.UniqueResult<HeaderDTO>();
    EndTime = DateTime.Now;
    SecondTry = EndTime - StartTime;

    tx.Commit();
}
```